List<T>.IndexOf returns -1 no matter what the input is
StoredObj is a list that contains GameObjects, and ObjAmount is a list that Contains integers, in case that helps.
    public void RemoveObjInv(GameObject InvObj, int amount)
    {
        ChangeObjTag InvObjScript = InvObj.GetComponent<ChangeObjTag>();
        if (InvObjScript.Stored)
        {
            ObjAmount[StoredObj.IndexOf(InvObj)] -= amount;//error happens here
            if(ObjAmount[StoredObj.IndexOf(InvObj)] <= 0)
            {
                ObjAmount[StoredObj.IndexOf(InvObj)] = 0;
                StoredObj.Remove(InvObj);
                GameObject.Find(InvObj.name).SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

I will provide more details if needed.
I tested to see if this was an outside error by testing just index of, but it returns -1 when I know that it should be returning 2, even with no outside factors.

Implement Equals() and HashCode() methods for your GameObject class.

ive never heard of those methods before, ill be sure to test it out

The problem is that your two lists are not in sync. When removing an entry by calling StoredObj.Remove(InvObj); you should also call ObjAmount.RemoveAt(StoredObj.IndexOf(InvObj)); so that both lists always have the same count.
The easier way would be to use a Dictionary<GameObject, int>(); to keep track of the amounts.

turns out I was just inputting the wrong object into the list, I was adding a clone of the object, so this was just my own mistake.

when you return -1 as index, it means that InvObj is not in your list. two things you must check. first is that i dont undrestand this part(ObjAmount[StoredObj]) is your list an array of lists? or list of lists?.
if ObjAmount[StoredObj] is your list, theeeeen,,,
second:check if you already added this to your list.
you can print ObjAmount[StoredObj].count so you can know if the object is added to the list.

the problem is that its returning that, even when i know its in the list, also where in the script did i put ObjAmount[StoredObj]
